# UITableViewCell add button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add some buttons to custom cell, when I click the button and other buttons also change. How can I click a button without changing the other buttons?

```
enter code here
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SViewTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
        reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)clickMe:(UIButton *)sender
{
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = (SViewTableViewCell *)[[sender superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:openStr]) {
             [sender setTitle:closeStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
             [sender setTitle:openStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: I don't understand your question and we definitely need to know if you are using prototype cells in a Storyboard or creating the cells programatically at run time. You currently seem to have a mix of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a issue about tableView cell reuse again, you should set the button title in `cellForRow` to keep reuse cell have a correct title, you should try code like this:

`openDict` is a NSMutableArray you should define, and this just a example.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SViewTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
        reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section];        
    if (openDict[key] && [openDict[key] boolValue]) {
        [sender setTitle:openStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [sender setTitle:closeStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    cell.cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}

- (void)clickMe:(UIButton *)sender
{
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = (SViewTableViewCell *)[[sender superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section];        
        if (openDict[key] && [openDict[key] boolValue]) {
             openDict[key] = @(0);
             [sender setTitle:closeStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
             openDict[key] = @(1);
             [sender setTitle:openStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: is not the way to write new code - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: guarantees a valid cell so there is no more check for a nil cell. Given that you need to come up with some way to check for an existing button before unconditionally adding one. Then you're in a mess involving hacks with tags etc. - don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! openDict is a NSMutableArray?

Comment: Same problem as the other answers: Does not use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: (no need to check if(cell == nil) post-iOS6 SDK.)

Answer (score 1):

Please set tag for each button in custom tableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SViewTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
        reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Archaic. Does not use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: (no need to check if(cell == nil) post-iOS6 SDK.)

Answer (score 0):

To add a button to a UITableViewCell you should do it at the time you configure the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - this is after you get the cell to reuse. If you want to add a button to a small number of cells you should cause that cell to be reloaded using UITableView's – `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method or `reloadData` to give you the opportunity to reload all cells.

Any subview you add to a cell should be added to the cell's `contentView` as a subview. You should remove all such views in `prepareForReuse` or you could find cell reuse makes extra buttons appear in cells you don't want to have buttons. Because of the need to prepare cells for reuse it is probably best to subclass UITableViewCell and to provide methods on the subclass to add buttons.

Another way is to register multiple kinds of cells for reuse with the table view, choosing what kind of cell to retrieve and use based on the data backing your table view. This is as simple as using `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` once for each kind of cell, then applying right reuse identifier in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` - you'll still be subclassing the cell objects but you configure them further in the class rather than at the time they are dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SViewTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)clickMe:(UIButton *)sender {
    SViewTableViewCell *cell = (SViewTableViewCell *)[[[sender superview]superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [self keepSelectionRemainsSameForIndexPath:indexPath andSender:sender];
}

- (void)keepSelectionRemainsSameForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath andSender:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == indexPath.row) {
        if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: openStr]) {
            [sender setTitle:closeStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [sender setTitle: openStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Archaic. Does not use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: (no need to check if(cell == nil) post-iOS6 SDK.)